# Apply binom.test to every row using columns as arguments?

Tags: r, plyr, purrr, mapply, do.call

I realize that this kind of question has been asked before, but I don't understand why my code is breaking.

I have tried `mapply` alone and with `do.call` as well as the `purrr` package's `pmap` function. I keep getting "unused argument" errors among others. Since all 3 keep failing, I figure I must be referencing my data incorrectly in the arguments. I have used `mdply` from the `plyr` package to do something like this, but that was over a year ago. Of course, any alternative approaches would be appreciated too.

To create the dataframe, `compar`:

```
obs = floor(runif(500, 1,99))
p = round(runif(500,0,1), digits = 4)
n = floor(runif(500, 100,150))
test = rep("two.sided", 500)
conf = rep(0.95, 500)

compar = as.data.frame(cbind(obs,n, p))    
compar$test = test
compar$conf = conf
head(compar, 3)
  obs      p   n      test conf
1  47 0.2432 133 two.sided 0.95
2  52 0.3391 118 two.sided 0.95
3  22 0.2790 115 two.sided 0.95
```

I try `pmap`:

```
pmap(.l = compar, .f = binom.test)
Error in .f(obs = .l[[c(1L, i)]], p = .l[[c(2L, i)]], n = .l[[c(3L, i)]],  : 
  unused arguments (obs = .l[[c(1, i)]], test = .l[[c(4, i)]])
```

Next up, `mapply`:

```
mapply(compar, FUN = binom.test)
Error in (function (x, n, p = 0.5, alternative = c("two.sided", "less",  : 
  incorrect length of 'x'
```

Finally, `do.call` and `mapply`

```
do.call(mapply, c(binom.test, compar[c("obs", "n", "p", "test", "conf")]))
Error in (function (x, n, p = 0.5, alternative = c("two.sided", "less",  : 
  unused arguments (obs = dots[[1]][[1]], test = dots[[4]][[1]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column names don't match `binom.test` arguments; For the `pmap` version, renaming the columns according to `binom.test` arguments should work:

```
pmap(select(compar, x=obs, n, p, alternative=test, conf), binom.test)

#[[1]]

#   Exact binomial test

#data:  .l[[c(1L, i)]] and .l[[c(2L, i)]]
#number of successes = 5, number of trials = 149, p-value < 2.2e-16
#alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.435
#95 percent confidence interval:
# 0.01098400 0.07657136
#sample estimates:
#probability of success 
#            0.03355705 


#[[2]]

#   Exact binomial test

#data:  .l[[c(1L, i)]] and .l[[c(2L, i)]]
#number of successes = 20, number of trials = 113, p-value = 1.391e-10
#alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.4681
#95 percent confidence interval:
# 0.1115928 0.2600272
#sample estimates:
#probability of success 
#             0.1769912 

# more output
```

Or: `pmap(rename(compar, x=obs, alternative=test), binom.test)`

Comment: Ah, I assumed pmap would respect position, not the column names. That makes sense. I'll try that with my actual data.